# Calculating change from 2 inputs by a user

Tags: java

i am trying to output the minimum amount of notes needed from two inputs. one being the cost and the other being the amount handed over by the customer.

so if i enter 400 and then 500, it should say 2 $50 dollars notes.
or if i enter 60 and then 80, it should say 1 $20 dollar note.

this is a small bit of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bank {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Enter amount due: ");
     int amount = input.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Amount tendered: ");
     int tmp = input.nextInt();

     int change;

     if(amount >= 50)
         {
         change =(tmp - amount)/50;
         System.out.println (change + " $50 bills");

         }

     if(amount >= 20)
     {
         change =(tmp - amount)/20;
         System.out.println (change + " $20 bills");

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using mod operator `%`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter amount due: ");
    int amount = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Amount tendered: ");
    int tmp = input.nextInt();

    int change;

    int diff = tmp - amount;
    if (diff % 50 == 0) {
        change = diff / 50;
        System.out.println(change + " $50 bills");

    } 
    else if (diff % 20 == 0) {
        change = diff / 20;
        System.out.println(change + " $20 bills");

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how would i get it to do just one or the other? so if the change is $100, the change should just be 2 $50 notes

Answer (score 0):

Once you calculate the amount of change in a value of a bill, you need to lower the amount of change required. This is done in the code `changeRequired = changeRequired - change;`

```
 System.out.println("Amount tendered: ");
 int tmp = input.nextInt();

 int changeRequired = tmp - amount;    

 int change;

 if(amount >= 50)
     {
     change =(changeRequired)/50;
     changeRequired = changeRequired - change;
     System.out.println (change + " $50 bills");

     }

 if(amount >= 20)
 {
     change =(changeRequired )/20;
     changeRequired = changeRequired - change;
     System.out.println (change + " $20 bills");

 }
```

Comment: thanks, but how would i get it to do just one or the other? so if the change is $100, the change should just be 2 $50 notes

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your change which is the variable `amount`, you can use the following code to find out how many notes of each of the $50, $20, $10, $5, $1 there are in the change. The number of notes is minimal.

```
numOf50 = 0; // number of $50 dollar bills, the rest is similar.
numOf20 = 0; // ...
numOf10 = 0; // ...
numOf5 = 0;
numOf1 = 0;


    if (amount / 50 > 1){
        numOf50 += (amount / 50);
        amount %= 50; // update the amount with the remainder
    }
    else if (amount / 20 > 1){
        numOf20 += (amount /20);
        amount %= 20;
    }
    else if (amount / 10 > 1){
        numOf10 += (amount / 10);
        amount %= 10;
    }
    else if (amount / 5 > 1){
        numOf5 += (amount / 5);
        amount %= 5;
    }
    else if (amount <=5 && amount >0){
        numOf1 = amount;
    }
// output is trivial, omitted.
```

Haven't tested on a machine but it should work or give you an idea.